# Can diodes be tested successfully in situ?

Tags: pcb, diodes, multimeter, testing, component-failure

I have tested a bunch of diodes in situ on a washing machine PCB. One comes back as expected with values of 0.6v and OL depending on testing direction.  The rest show the same 0.6v in the expected direction while 1.4v where I would expect OL. The resources I have read suggest that failed diodes should either show the 0.6 OR OL in both directions and make no mention of a higher value.

Does this high value indicate a failure of the diode or an error in attempting to test in situ?

Comment: No, they cannot generally. As can't any component type (generally).

Comment: Without knowing the test parameters you are using it is difficult to give a clear answer. Can you show the test arrangement (circuitry, applied voltage, meter connections, measurement range settings, etc) that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. Let's assume any capacitor is discharged fully, otherwise you can get odd effects such as negative resistance readings or smoke emissions from the DMM. Let's also assume that you know it's actually a diode and not something diode-like in appearance like a diac.

Even if you don't understand the circuit, if you get a higher than 0.6V-ish reading in *both* directions then the diode is bad. That's unlikely in practice without corresponding visual indication such as a cracked diode or diode with the leads blown off it.

If you are getting a dead short in both directions it may be worth unsoldering the diode to measure it out of circuit. This is the more likely case for a diode failure without corresponding visual and/or olfactory sequelae.

A reading of 0.6-ish in one direction and something rather higher in the other direction is *probably* an indication the diode is okay.